# efficient way to get string between the two words

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, string, list

I have a list of strings as:

```
strings= ['stackasdf:5;iwantthis123jasdoverflow','iwantthistoo','asdf:5;python123jasd']
```

Now, I want to print strings both in between two substrings`(start=asdf:5; end=123jasd)` and which are not.

output expected:

```
iwantthis
iwantthistoo
python
```

What I've done is:

```
import re
start = 'asdf:5;'
end = '123jasd'
for i in strings:
    t=i[len(start):-len(end)]
    if t:
        print (t)
    else:
        print (i)

df:5;iwantthis123jasdo 
iwantthistoo 
python
```

I'm not getting the desired output as expected.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is unclear what the OP is asking for based on the comments in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Using a regex approach we can try:

```py
strings = ['stackasdf:5;iwantthis123jasdoverflow','iwantthistoo','asdf:5;python123jasd']
output = [re.findall(r'asdf:5;(.*?)123jasd', x)[0] if re.search(r'asdf:5(.*?)123jasd', x) else x for x in strings]
print(output)  # ['iwantthis', 'iwantthistoo', 'python']
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. But, I don't want list of strings as i want to append it in another array.

Comment: I have provided a correct and efficient answer based on the question you asked above.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a simple for each loop and if statement to print out the correct substring of each element in the array:

```
strings=  ['stackasdf:5;iwantthis123jasdoverflow','iwantthistoo','asdf:5;python123jasd']

for word in strings:
    if "asdf:5;" in word and "123jasd" in word:
      ind1 = word.index("asdf:5;")
      ind2 = word.index("123jasd")
      print(word[ind1+7:ind2])
    else:
      print(word)
```

output:

```
iwantthis
iwantthistoo
python
```

Comment: I'm looking for more efficient way to do this as I have list of thousands of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Use replace function & split?

```
strings = ['stackasdf:5;iwantthis123jasdoverflow',
           'iwantthistoo',
           'asdf:5;python123jasd']
for i in strings:
    c = '\n'  # c may be any character that is not present in your strings
    i = i.replace('asdf:5;', c).replace('123jasd', c).split(c)
    print(i[0] if len(i) == 1 else i[1])
print(f'{strings = }')  # to show that I am not changing the original list.
```

Output:

```
iwantthis
iwantthistoo
python
strings = ['stackasdf:5;iwantthis123jasdoverflow', 'iwantthistoo', 'asdf:5;python123jasd']
```